# Expected value of item in a sorted list of integers

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, genetic-algorithms

If you were to take random positive integers, put them into a list, and sort them is there anyway to find the expected value of the kth item in the list? The list is sorted in ascending order.

By random positive integer I mean some number in the range 0-N where the probability of each number occurring is equal. (I think what I'm trying to say is uniform distribution).

Comment: What is the relationship between the fitness of the child and the fitnesses of its parents?

Comment: Values in the child vector are determined from the parents by taking the value at index i from parent A and the value at index i from parent B and testing if the absolute value of their difference is greater than a threshold. If it is the child receives a random value in the range 0-N. If it is less than the threshold the child receives the parents value at index i. Simply put the algorithm tries to preserve any similarities in the parent vectors (In hopes that the similarities are what made them fit, hence the sorting before hand).

Comment: For this question to be answerable you would need to be more specific about how "random" values are chosen (what are their probabilities?) You also need to explain how a "random value in the range 0-N" is consistent with a "vector of positive integers." Also, are the references to "N" in the first paragraph and the second paragraph really to the same value?

Comment: By random I mean that each value in the range 0-N inclusive has an equal probability (I'm sure there's a better term for that I just do know the words). What I should have said with regards to your second comment is the child at index i receives a random value in the range 0-N. And yes N is the same as it was in the first paragraph. Thank you for helping me add some detail to this question!

Comment: I edited the question, a description of the algorithm is not as important and it seems to be taking away from my true question. I just need to know what extra information about the expected values I can get from the fact that the list is sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be precise, suppose that $k$ integers $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_k$ are uniformly and independently drawn from the set $S = \{0,1,\ldots, N\}$ *with replacement.*

Let $x$ be any value in $S$.  Then the chance that the $r^\text{th}$ smallest of the $y_i$ (written $y_{[r]}$) is less than or equal to $x$ is the chance that $r$ *or more* of the $y_i$ are less than or equal to $x$.  The number of $y_i$ less than or equal to $x$ has a [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $p=(x+1)/(N+1)$ (the chance of the outcome being in the set $\{0,1,\ldots, x\}$) and $k$ (the number of "trials").  Therefore (taking $N$ and $k$ as given),

$$\Pr(y_{[r]}\le x) = \sum_{i=r}^k \binom{k}{i} p^i(1-p)^{k-i}.$$

From this we compute

$$p(x,r,k,N) = \Pr(y_{[r]}= x) = \Pr(y_{[r]}\le x) - \Pr(y_{[r]}\le x-1),$$

understanding $\Pr(y_{[r]}\le -1) = 0$, and obtain the expectation directly from its definition,

$$\mathbb{E}[y_{[r]}] = \sum_{x=0}^N p(x,r,k,N) x.$$

For example, letting $N=10$ and $k=7$, the expectations for $y_{[1]}$ through $y_{[7]}$ are

$$0.927812, 2.250436, 3.624783, 5.000000, 6.375217, 7.749564, 9.072188.$$

For sufficiently large $N$, the expectation of $y_{[r]}$ will be approximately $rN/(k+1)$.

---

`R` code to perform these calculations follows.  Begin with computing $p(x,r,k,N)$:

```r
prob <- function(x, r, n, k) {
  p <- (x+1)/(n+1)
  if (p>=1) return (1)
  if (p<=0) return (0)
  i <- r:k
  sum(choose(k, i) * p^i * (1-p)^(k-i))
}
```

This should be replaced by better code for large $k$, such as system-supplied code to compute binomial probabilities, as in

```r
prob <- function(x, r, n, k) pbinom(r-1, k,  (x+1)/(n+1), lower.tail=FALSE)
```

However it is implemented, `prob` can be used by differencing, multiplying by the `x`, and summing:

```r
> n <- 10; k <- 7
> zapsmall(sapply(1:k, function(i) 
     sum(diff(sapply(-1:n, function(x) prob(x, i, n, k))) * 0:n)))

[1] 0.927812 2.250436 3.624783 5.000000 6.375217 7.749564 9.072188
```

A more efficient implementation uses [summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts):

```r
> zapsmall(n - sapply(1:k, function(i) sum(sapply(-1:(n-1), function(x) prob(x, i, n, k)))))

[1] 0.927812 2.250436 3.624783 5.000000 6.375217 7.749564 9.072188
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, this is exactly what I needed!